# Error in Inserting value in a table using trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am trying to insert a value into a table using trigger concept but i am getting error below is my code

```
1  create or replace trigger trig_sub
2  before insert on subscription
3  for each row
4  declare
5  m purchases.msisdn%type;
6  c purchases.circleid%type;
7  con purchases.contentproviderid%type;
8  pac purchases.packagepriceoptionid%type;
9  p purchases.packageid%type;
10 o purchases.operatorid%type;
11 pt purchases.purchasetime%type;
12 mes purchases.messagestatus%type;
13 ts purchases.traiservicekey%type;
14 ubs number(5):=0;
15 sq number(5);
16 extm date;
17 cursor cur_pur is select msisdn,circleid,contentproviderid,packagepriceoptionid,packageid,
   operatorid,purchasetime,messagestatus,traiservicekey from purchases where 
   eventype<>'Content Purchase' and status=1;
18 begin
19 select sub1.next,sysdate+5 into sq,extm from dual;
20 open cur_pur;
21 loop
22 fetch cur_pur into m,c,con,pac,p,o,pt,mes,ts;
23 exit when cur_pur%notfound;
24 if(m=old.msisdn) then
25 if(old.unsubscribdbyuser=1) then
26 insert into subscription(subscriptionid,packageid,subscriptiontime,xpirytime,
   unsubscribedbyuser,remark,packagepriceid,operatorid,contentproviderid,circleid,
   traiservicekey) values(sq,p,pt,extm,ubs,mes,pac,o,con,c,ts);
27 elsif(old.unsubscribdbyuser=0) then
28 update subscription set lastrenewaltime=sysdate and lastrenewalattempttime=sysdate and 
   expirytime=sysdate+5 and modifiedtime=sysdate;
29 end if;
30 else 
31 insert into subscription(subscriptionid,packageid,subscriptiontime,xpirytime,
   unsubscribedbyuser,remark,packagepriceid,operatorid,contentproviderid,circleid,
   traiservicekey) values(sq,p,pt,extm,ubs,mes,pac,o,con,c,ts);
32 end if;
33 end loop;
34 close cur_pur;
35 end trig_sub;
36 /
```

and here is the error :

trigger created with compiler errors.

> show errors trigger trig_sub;
>   19/1   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   19/49  PL/SQL: ORA-00933: old.msisdn must be declare

Can anybody please tell me why i am facing this error as i am new to this concept and technology
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You are referring to the rows before the dml operation as `old` instead of `:old` (notice the colon ). E.g., lines 24-25 should read:

```
24 if(m=:old.msisdn) then
25 if(:old.unsubscribdbyuser=1) then
```